# Problem with sleep() function

Tags: python, pi-2

With this code I found on the internet and changed a little bit for measuring temperature I cannot write to the log file when the sleep value is more then 1.

The log file is created but stays empty. With sleep value 1 there are no problems.

```py
import subprocess
import logging
import time
from time import sleep, gmtime, strftime

#Read temp from MCP9808 sensor (Using SPI interface)
import smbus
t_reg = 0x05
address = 0x18
bus = smbus.SMBus(1) # change to 0 for older RPi revision

reading = bus.read_i2c_block_data(address, t_reg)
# t = (reading[0] &lt:&lt: 8) + reading[1] 
t = (reading[0] << 8) + reading[1]


#Calculate temperature (see 5.1.3.1 in datasheet)
# temp = t &amp; 0x0FFF
def get_temp():
    temp = t & 0x0FFF
    temp /=  16.0
    return(temp)

# if (t &amp; 0x1000):
if (t & 0x1000):
    temp -= 256
# try:
#   MCP_Temp='%.1f' % (temp*(9.0/5.0)+32.0) #Converts to Farenheit
# except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
#   print e

#This will add a timestamp to and temp in a CSV ready format
# output=strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M,") + ',' + str(float(temp))
# print output

with open("cpu_temp.csv", "a") as log:
    while True:
        temp = get_temp()       
        log.write("{0},{1}\n".format(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),str(temp)))
#       sleep(30)
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you call "get_temp" multiple times, but in there you refer to the variable "t" which is only set on the initial run.

```python
import subprocess
import logging
import time
from time import sleep, gmtime, strftime
import smbus

#Constant things, that don't change during run.
t_reg = 0x05
address = 0x18
bus = smbus.SMBus(1) # change to 0 for older RPi revision

#Calculate temperature (see 5.1.3.1 in datasheet)
# temp = t &amp; 0x0FFF
def get_temp():
    #The reading variable changes every time you run get_temp()
    reading = bus.read_i2c_block_data(address, t_reg)
    t = (reading[0] << 8) + reading[1]
    temp = t & 0x0FFF
    temp /=  16.0
    # if (t &amp; 0x1000):
    if (t & 0x1000):
      temp -= 256
    return(temp)


# try:
#   MCP_Temp='%.1f' % (temp*(9.0/5.0)+32.0) #Converts to Farenheit
# except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
#   print e

#This will add a timestamp to and temp in a CSV ready format
# output=strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M,") + ',' + str(float(temp))
# print output

with open("cpu_temp.csv", "a") as log:
    while True:
        temp = get_temp()       
        log.write("{0},{1}\n".format(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),str(temp)))
#       sleep(30)
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Is it possible that you rewrite the code like you describe

Comment: I did. Have a look at line 14 and following.